# How to make Keyboard Button message text different from its caption in Telegram bot API using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

i need my bot to print a different message than its caption

for example : button text = Turkish To English
              print message = /Turkish_To_English

```
def Start_Method(bot, update):
chat_id = update.message.chat_id
bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, 'typing')
User_name = update.message.chat.first_name
bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Welcome Dear')
keyboard = [['Turkish To English'],
            ['Turkish To Persian']]

bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Select : ', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True))
```